# Subquery retunrs more than 1 row issue with JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on one project and facing one issue while using some joins..
I have diff tables and columns like:

**tblpackages as a**

```
packagename 

packageid

stateid

packageduration

seater_4

seater_7

seater_14
```

**tblstates as b**

```
statename

stateid
```

**tblpackage_packagetypes as c**

```
packagetypeid

packageid
```

**tblpackagetype as d**

```
packagetypeid

packagetypename
```

**tblpackageplaces as e**

```
packageid

placeid
```

**tblplaces as f**

```
placeid
```

**tblpackagedurations as g**

```
packageid

days

hotelid

placeid
```

**tblhotels as h**

```
hotelid
```

and my query is as:

```
 select a.packagename as packagename, a.packageid as packageid, 
    a.packageduration as days, a.seater_4, a.seater_7, a.seater_14,
    b.statename,
    substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select f.placename )  SEPARATOR ', 
    '),',',4) placename,
    substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select d.packagetypename )  SEPARATOR 
    ', '),',',4) packagetypename,
    (select sum(g.days) from tblpackagedurations g group by a.packageid )
    from tblpackages a
    join tblstates b on b.stateid = a.stateid              
    join tblpackage_packagetypes c on c.packageid = a.packageid
    join tblpackagetype d on d.packagetypeid = c.packagetypeid
    join tblpackageplaces e on e.packageid = a.packageid
    join tblplaces f on f.placeid = e.placeid
    join tblpackagedurations g on g.packageid = a.packageid
    join tblhotels h on h.hotelid = g.hotelid
                        where b.statename = 'jammu and kashmir'
                         group by a.packageid, g.packageid
```

and the output for days as:

```
packageid     days
**************************
1              10

2              10

3              10

4              10
```

the value of days in durations as:

```
packageid     days
**************************
1              2

2              2

3              2

4              2

4              2
```

the output should be

```
1    2

2    2 

3     2

4     4
```

But its not as per expectation and if change group by from a.package to d i.packageid i got error as subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: hi, non one used SQL... Quiet strange :(

Comment: Your expected result has 2 columns, but your query selects 10 columns. Make it easy to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what does this mean by 2 columns. can you elaborate this

Comment: if u are talking about the result of duration then it must be the sum of on the bases of package id and finally display as per group by packageid

Answer (score 0):

IF i have really understood your problem (difficult without see your data) you have to make aggregate function of the field you don't group by:

```
select a.packagename as packagename, a.packageid as packageid, 
sum(a.packageduration) as days, a.seater_4, a.seater_7, a.seater_14,
b.statename,
substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select f.placename )  SEPARATOR ', 
'),',',4) placename,
substring_index(GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (select d.packagetypename )  SEPARATOR 
', '),',',4) packagetypename,
(select sum(g.days) from tblpackagedurations g group by a.packageid )
from tblpackages a
join tblstates b on b.stateid = a.stateid              
join tblpackage_packagetypes c on c.packageid = a.packageid
join tblpackagetype d on d.packagetypeid = c.packagetypeid
join tblpackageplaces e on e.packageid = a.packageid
join tblplaces f on f.placeid = e.placeid
join tblpackagedurations g on g.packageid = a.packageid
join tblhotels h on h.hotelid = g.hotelid
                    where b.statename = 'jammu and kashmir'
                     group by a.packageid, g.packageid
```

Comment: hi @A Colonna,
If i simply use my query without tblpackagedurations and tblhotels than I am able to achieve correct result for the desired columns,
When I add extra table tblpackagedurations as inner join and try to fetch the days sum and group by as packageid the output is same as i shared above.

As there are many duration for any package and thats why group by package id is imp...

as I am also using aggregate  function to for total duration of any package by SUM